# Wiring a charger to a battery

Tags: electric-circuits

I have an AC to DC charger and a battery that have mismatched connectors. I stick my voltmeter in and determine the positive and negative terminals of each. The negative is the one with the black wire when voltage is positive and the black wire is in the com slot. So to give the battery power, i would connect the negative to negative and positive to positive?

https://ibb.co/bSEroz

I don’t want to explode anything.

Comment: What is the voltage of the charger?  What is the voltage of the battery?  Are you sure the battery is the rechargeable type?  If the connectors are mismatched, there may be a reason for the mismatch, as some designs purposefully do this to prevent connecting two incompatible devices.

Comment: 42v 2a DC charger and a 10s 18650 lithium ion. So it should work using the max voltage for 18650 at 4.2v * 10.

Comment: Also I went to the store (an actual physical store, not online!) and bought the proper connector, and everything works. No explosion (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Yes]

Negative(positive) terminal of charger should be connected to negative(positive) terminal of the battery. In this way the negative terminal of battery acquires negative charge and positive terminal acquires positive charge, thereby increasing the potential of the battery. Doing other way round would discharge your battery further and keeping in such configuration for long enough time will potentially damage the battery.

Comment: Please note that this would be considered an engineering question, not a physics one.  There's a specific reason to close for that kind of question.